Lefschetz Theorem in Dolgachev's On automorphisms of Enriques Surfaces
Let $F$ be a Enriques surface over $\Bbb C$. I have a question about a detail in the proof of Proposition 2.1. from Dolgachev's On automorphisms of Enriques surfaces. 
This 2.1. Proposition. states that if $F$ is an Enriques surface, then $H_F:= \operatorname{Pic}(F)/\operatorname{Tors}$ is an even unimodular lattice of rank 10 with certain signature.
Now the proof argues as follows:

By the Hodge decomposition, we have
$\operatorname{Pic}(F)=H^2(F,\Bbb Z), H^1(F,\Bbb Z)=\operatorname{Tors}$. By the formula $12(1-q+p_g)=K_F^2+c_2$, we get $H^2(F,\Bbb Z)/\operatorname{Tors}=\Bbb Z^{10}$ By Lefschetz, $\operatorname{Tors}(\operatorname{Pic}(F))= \operatorname{Tors}(H^2(F,\Bbb Z)$. By Poincare,
$H_F= H^2(F,\Bbb Z)/\operatorname{Tors}$ is a unimodular lattice.

Question: The Lefschetz argument I not understood.
I'm not completely sure, but presumably Dolgachev refers to this Lefschetz theorem which states that the map $ \operatorname{Pic}(F) \to H^2(F,\Bbb Z) \to H^2(F,\Bbb C)$ obtained as composition first Chern map $c_1$ together with canonical inclusion $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb C$ of constant sheaves, factors surjectively onto $H^2(F,\Bbb Z) \cap H^{1,1}(F)$ where the latter term comes from Hodge decompotion $H^2(F,\Bbb C)=H^{2,0} \oplus H^{1,1} \oplus H^{0,2} $.
Why from this follows $\operatorname{Tors}(\operatorname{Pic}(F))= \operatorname{Tors}(H^2(F,\Bbb Z))$?
(That's the thing, the question is not about why that holds, but why it's a consequence of Lefschetz as Dolgachev stated there)
By the way, Enriques condition implies $H^1(F, \mathcal{O}_F)=H^2(F, \mathcal{O}_F)=0$, so by complex exponential sequence we obtain already $\operatorname{Pic}(F)=H^2(F,\Bbb Z)$ as Abelian groups, so isn't Lefschetz application there redundant as we can just take torsion of both groups?
If not and there is more involved, any idea to what Dolgachev refering to  there by application of Lefschetz to get this statementon torsions?

The Lefschetz result Dolgachev mentions is the isomorphism $\operatorname{Pic}(F)\cong H^2(F,\mathbb{Z}) $ when $H^{i}(F,\mathcal{O}_F)$ for $i=1,2$.

@abx: hmm, what makes me a bit suspicious if that is really the reason why Dolgachev invoked Lefschetz is that one line before he already stated that $\operatorname{Pic}(F)=H^2(F,\Bbb Z)$ should hold due to Hodge decomposition. But that's also a strange reasoning, as a priori HD alone not gives this iso. What obvious that Dolgachev definitely not invokes there the exactness of LES of exponential sequence, as then in light of Enriquesness Lefschetz and HD would be redundant.

...this proof has a strange causal order... or I not understand it

If you understand a proof of each assertion, why does it matter what Dolgachev meant by “Lefschetz”?

@JasonStarr: Because this may unravel a technique which up to wasn't familar to me, so I would like to understand how Dolgachev reasoned there, even though surely one could reason differently (eg exponential sequence) :)

There is no theorem in mathematics that unravels because Dolgachev accidentally wrote the name "Lefschetz".
